# How to create a new folder by python google drive api and what is the use of MediaFileUpload?

Tags: python, desktop-application, google-drive-api

Right now, I am writing a python desktop application. I want to create a folder in my google drive account by google drive api but I don't know how to do it. I have seen the example of Files: insert on API reference, but this function only seems to upload a file existing in my computer. How can I create a folder?
Furthermore, can I create any type of file by google drive API and what is the use of function MediaFileUpload?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a folder is documented [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/folder). On that same page, you'll also find information on specifying MIME type (to answer your second question).

MediaFileUpload is a class and not a function. Commented code for this class is [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-drive-sdk-samples/source/browse/python/lib/apiclient/http.py).

Comment: Thank you very much and I have solved that problem as I modified the Google example a little.   body = {
    'title': title,
    'description': description,
    'mimeType': mime_type
  }
  # Set the parent folder.
  if parent_id:
    body['parents'] = [{'id': parent_id}]

  try:
    file = service.files().insert(
        body=body).execute()

    # Uncomment the following line to print the File ID
    # print 'File ID: %s' % file['id']

    return file
  except errors.HttpError, error:
    print 'An error occured: %s' % error
    return None